# A single friendly word for something that is uninteresting and boring?

Tags: word-request

I'd like to describe something as uninteresting, dull, boring, but in a friendly manner that doesn't make anyone feel put off or feel sad.

I could perhaps write "not super interesting". That would make the point, I think, without using any negative words.

But I'm looking for a single word. Is there no single friendly and respectful word for something that is uninteresting plus perhaps a bit boring / dull?

Comment: How to speak in a manner that doesn't make people feel sad is off-topic.

Comment: There is a phrase, "Damned by faint praise"… an example - after spending the day at the fun-fair, to tell your host it was "interesting" would do the trick. Who wants an interesting fun-fair, you want an exciting one.

Comment: Do you have a word for that in your native language ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Hmm... That'd be in Swedish. Not that I can think of, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Drab](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/drab).

> Lacking brightness or interest; drearily dull.

Answer (score 1):

[Unexciting](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unexciting)?

> Not exciting; dull.

Unfortunately, it's going to be difficult to phrase this in a "friendly" manner since you're essentially saying you don't like their thing/task... whatever it is.

[Uninspiring](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/uninspiring) could work

> Not producing excitement or interest

And some other options on the [thesaurus](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english-thesaurus/uninspiring) under *uninspiring*:

> boring, dull, dreary, unexciting, unstimulating, uninvolving;
>   
> dry, colorless, bland, lackluster, tedious, flaccid, formulaic, humdrum, run-of-the-mill, by-the-numbers

And under *[uninteresting](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english-thesaurus/uninteresting)*:

> unexciting, boring, dull, tiresome, wearisome, soporific, tedious, jejune, lifeless, lackluster, humdrum, colorless, soulless, bland, insipid, banal, dry, dreary, drab, pedestrian, uninvolving, lacking

Comment: I thought of _pedestrian_. Another I thought of (surprisingly, not in your list) is _mundane._

Comment: @J.R. Interesting. It was on the list on another thesaurus site... along with many other options. There are lots of words for this, though I'd argue that few of them fit the "friendly" requirement.

Comment: @Catija Yes perhaps there's no really good word. And even if there was, eventually it might get tainted by the fact that it means that one thought whatever-it-was actually was a bit uninteresting/boring/dull.

Comment: @KajMagnus You can always look at it from the point of view of "what if we did *this* instead". Rather than saying "no" to the uninteresting thing, is a way to **make**  it interesting?

Comment: @J.R. *pedestrian* and *mundane* feel a bit better for me than *boring* and *dull*, although they seem to mean roughly the same things. Perhaps the reason I feel better about those words, is that I'm not used to hearing/seeing them, and therefore I don't have any bad feelings about them. Uncommon words might feel better :-)

Comment: @KajMagnus But, depending on the person you're talking to and their level of English, they may not understand what you're saying... which would just cause them to ask what you mean.

Comment: @Catija Yes, actually, I won't use those two words because of that.

Comment: @Kaj - You can sometimes soften negative words like these with qualifiers. Sure, "That movie was mundane," isn't much different than "That movie was dull," but if you say, "That movie was just a little too mundane for my liking," or, "That was a tad bit pedestrian," it's less likely to sound overly negative. Sometimes the solution isn't one elusive magic word, but the surrounding words that couch your remarks. (I'm guessing that's the reason for the downvote, too – some people get frustrated with requests that demand a single word rather than ask about how to best communicate something.)

Comment: I swear I'd made another comment... essentially saying that it might be worth it to consider recommending an alternate option or an alternate method rather than simply declining this one... though declining is well within your right!

Comment: @Catija When you wrote, "declining this one", what were you referring to? Declining what? Thanks anyway for your answer and the suggestions/clarifications.

Comment: @KajMagnus declining an invitation. The implication of your question is that you either had received an invitation/request for aid from someone.

Comment: @Catija Oh actually the context is something else: my question was related to something I'm building with computers, a hobby project.